# Print single word from Parsed Json text

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, csv, twitter

Here is the raw data I am working with prior to my code. (I get this data from the Twitter API after my code makes the call)

```
{"metadata":{"result_type":"recent","iso_language_code":"et"}
"created_at":"Tue Dec 03 01:41:53 +0000 2013","id":407686093790662656,"id_str":"407686093790662656","text":"@emblems123 justinbieberfan12599@gamil.com","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":407677310821613569,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":"407677310821613569","in_reply_to_user_id":2201997043,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":"2201997043","in_reply_to_screen_name":"emblems123","user":{"id":1220098345,"id_str":"1220098345","name":"PYD","screen_name":"bieberfan12599","location":
```

I run the below code:

```
import csv
import json
import oauth2 as oauth
import urllib
import sys
import requests
import time

CONSUMER_KEY = ""
CONSUMER_SECRET = ""
ACCESS_KEY = ""
ACCESS_SECRET = ""

class TwitterSearch:
    def __init__(self,
        ckey    = CONSUMER_KEY,
        csecret = CONSUMER_SECRET,
        akey    = ACCESS_KEY,
        asecret = ACCESS_SECRET,
        query   = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.{mode}?{query}'
    ):
        consumer     = oauth.Consumer(key=ckey, secret=csecret)
        access_token = oauth.Token(key=akey, secret=asecret)
        self.client  = oauth.Client(consumer, access_token)
        self.query   = query

    def search(self, q, mode='json', **queryargs):
        queryargs['q'] = q
        query = urllib.urlencode(queryargs)
        return self.client.request(self.query.format(query=query, mode=mode))

def write_csv(fname, rows, header=None, append=False, **kwargs):
    filemode = 'ab' if append else 'wb'
    with open(fname, filemode) as outf:
        out_csv = csv.writer(outf, **kwargs)
        if header:
            out_csv.writerow(header)
        out_csv.writerows(rows)

def main():
    ts = TwitterSearch()
    response, data = ts.search('@gmail.com', result_type='recent')
    js = json.loads(data)
    search_terms = ['@gmail.com']
    matches = []
    for term in search_terms:
        match = [word for word in js if term in word]
        matches.append(match)
    messages = ([msg['created_at'], msg['text'], msg['user']['id'], matches[0]] for msg in js.get('statuses', []))
    write_csv('twitter_gmail.csv', messages, append=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the output which is in a .csv:

```
Fri Dec 13 03:49:06 +0000 2013,I need some HARD TRAP beats producers help me out here...louiethefifthonline@gmail.com,490060971,[]
```

My issues is I want it to print just the email address from the parsed JS text.  I have tried a split() but I cant do that with an expression.  Seems like no matter what I do it is always just blank "[]"

I really want to figure out how to have it print just the email address from the 'text' as a part of row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the data in a string then you can extract the email by using `regex`:

```
import re
string = "Fri Dec 13 03:49:06 +0000 2013,I need some HARD TRAP beats producers help me out here...louiethefifthonline@gmail.com,490060971,[]"
regex = "\w+@\w+\.com"
match = re.findall(regex,string)
print match
```

Output containing all the matches, *In this case one*:

```
['louiethefifthonline@gmail.com']
```

And even if you were to replace `string` with the string of the raw data you obtain by converting the `dict` to a string by using the `str()` function:

```
string = str({"metadata":{"result_type":"recent","iso_language_code":"et"},
            "created_at":"Tue Dec 03 01:41:53 +0000 2013","id":407686093790662656,"id_str":"407686093790662656","text":"@emblems123 justinbieberfan12599@gamil.com","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":False,"in_reply_to_status_id":407677310821613569,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":"407677310821613569","in_reply_to_user_id":2201997043,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":"2201997043","in_reply_to_screen_name":"emblems123","user":{"id":1220098345,"id_str":"1220098345","name":"PYD","screen_name":"bieberfan12599","location":"NY"}})
```

You will still be able to get the expected output of:

```
['justinbieberfan12599@gamil.com']
```